# Staggered sequenced substring in a cell for an entire row

Tags: excel

I am just wondering how would you replace a certain part of a string in a cell so that it is dependent on another cell.

If I have a an excel that looks similar to this

```
This is 1 || This is 1 || This is 1 || This is 1
blah      || blah      || blah      || blah
Part 1    || Part 1    || Part 1    || Part 1
```

How would I change it to something similar to this

```
This is 1 || This is 9 || This is 17 || This is 25
blah      || blah      ||  blah      || blah
Part 1    || Part 2    || Part 3     || Part 4
```

The first row is incremented by 8 every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select A1 and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. When the Format Cells dialog open, go to the Numbers tab and choose Custom from the list down the left. Supply hte following for the *Type:*

```
T\hi\s i\s 0
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to create the custom number format.

Put this formula into A1,

```
=(column(A:A)-1)*8+1
```

Fill right as necessary. A similar method could be applied to your third row.

[image: Blah blah blah]

If having honest-to-goodness real numbers to reference in row 1 is not at all important, then either of these formulas will accomplish the same thing.

```
=TEXT((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*8+1, "T\hi\s i\s 0")
="This is "& (COLUMN(A:A)-1)*8+1
```

Comment: Pretty cool. It took me a minute to realize you were using those backslashes as escape characters. I've never tried passing anything like that in the "Format_Text" parameter of the text function before.

Comment: It comes in handy when dealing with a format mask in VBA's [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx) as well as the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945). I hate dealing with quotes inside quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's not a number, it's a string, it would be cumbersome to write a formula to do the math on it.  You would have to use a substring to grab just the digit part.  Not impossible, but sloppy looking.  And it makes the spreadsheet do more work than it should.

What you should do is keep them separate.  So one cell holds the text "This is ", and a following cell holds the number.  Then you can easily use a formula to write it back out and display it to the user:  =A1 & sum(B1+8)

```
This is     1   This is 9   This is     9   This is 17
This is     2   This is 10  This is     10  This is 18
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a formula that will accomplish this without a lot of hassle, use this, assuming you start in cell A1:

```
MID(A1,1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1))&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1)+1,100)+8
```

You can extrapolate into the next rows as necessary. This will work if your text has 2 spaces, ie "This_is_" and a number. If your actual sheet has different text, you will need to adjust this.